# Java screen rendering

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to learn Java game developing in hopes of one day going to uni. I'm currently following tutorials and learning the basics. However, after following a tutorial my render doesn't render full, it only renders half of the intended screen. The following code are the 2 classes I've used. Have I messed up with constructors, scaling, is the `this.height` incorrect? I cant seem to figure it out.

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static int width = 300;
public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
public static int scale = 3;

private Thread thread;
private JFrame frame;
private boolean running = false;

private Screen screen;

private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, 
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    screen = new Screen(width, height);
    frame = new JFrame();

}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    try {
    thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {         
    while (running) {
        update();
        render();
    }
}

public void update() {

}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    screen.render();        
    for (int i  = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setTitle("My First Game");
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();

    }
}


public class Screen {

private int width, height;
public int[] pixels;

public Screen(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    pixels = new int[width * height];
}

public void render() {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
        for (int x = 0; x < height; x++ ) {
            pixels[x + y * width] =(0xFF00FF);
            }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn how to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some [complimentary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you still require assistance after doing so, please [edit] your question to clarify precisely where the problem lies.

Comment: Joe C, Thanks ill read upon the link soon! I've tried de bugging as best i can already. I still cant find out why it only renders half the screen as pink. I want to be able to render the entire screen pink!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render the whole screen pink you need make 2 adaptations:

1) Change the order of your operands when calculating the height on line 5, so that you multiply first and divide afterwards like this:

```
public static int height = width * 9 / 16;
```

Reason: The expression is evaluated from left to right. As all operators are integers, the result of each sub-expression is rounded down. See the difference:

```
300 / 16 * 9 = 18 * 9 = 162
```

vs

```
300 * 9 / 16 = 2700 / 16 = 168
```

2) There is a typo in the render method, where height is used twice instead of width. Therefore a rectangle is rendered. You need to change the `height` variable in the inner for loop to `width`.

```
public void render() {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) { // use width here instead of height
            pixels[x + y * width] = (0xFF00FF);
        }
    }
}
```